# Choose an integer from an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

How would I go about filter values of an arraylist and making one value of the list an integer? Like, if I wanted to check which of the values on the list is half of 10, how would I do that and then take that value and make it a lone variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a `for` loop. Assuming your `ArrayList` contains `Integer` objects:

```
Integer result = null;
for (Integer ii: myArrayList) {
    if (ii == (10/2))
    result = ii;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make use of `indexOf` method in `ArrayList`

```
int indexOfelement = arrayList.indexOf(elem);
```